# Show that if a series converges $\sum b_j$ converges then

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I show that if a series converges $\sum b_j$ converges then $\sum(b_j)^2$ converges.

My idea since $b_j$ converges then it is bounded. So $b_j<M$ and then

$b_j^2=b_j*b_j<M*b_j$

Thus $b_j^2$ is bounded by $M*B_j$ but how to show convergence.

Comment: It's false in general. It's true if the $b_j$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have $b_j \geqslant 0$, or $(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ is a counterexample.

$\sum_j b_j$ converges, so the convergence criterion implies $b_j \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$. Hence there is an $N$ so that $\lvert b_j \rvert <1$ for all $j>N$. Then for any $k>1$,
$$\sum_{j=N+1}^{N+k} b_j^2 \leqslant \sum_{j=N+1}^{N+k} b_j,$$
since $b_j^2\leqslant b_j$ for $0 \leqslant b_j < 1$. The result follows by the comparison test. (Note that the part of the sum below $N$ is finite and so irrelevent for convergence.)